# Category of Abelian Groups: Limits

Tags: category-theory, abelian-groups, limits-colimits

Let the category of Abelian Groups. 
I know that product and coproduct of a finite number of objects are the same in this category.
Then, it follows that the projective and injective limits of finite diagrams are the same?
Thanks.

Comment: You expect to be able to generalize, from limits and colimits of finite diagrams with _no arrows_ being equal, that limits and colimits are equal for any finite diagram?

Answer (score 3):

No.  For instance, for a diagram of the form $A\to B$ with two objects and an arrow between them, the limit will be $A$ and the colimit will be $B$ (this is true in any category).